# document:click not working

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to make a global click event directive. But document:click does not work for me.

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

@Directive(
  selector: '[clickOutside]'
)
class ClickOutsideDirective {

  @HostListener('click', [r'$event.target'])
  void onClick(targetElement){
    print('Target:' + targetElement.toString());
  }
}
```

When changing *document:click* to *click* I get expected behavior. But of course not globally. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `document:` and similar event scopes were removed in Dart.

Use instead

```
import 'dart:html';

class ClickOutsideDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  StreamSubscription _docClickSub;
  ngOnInit() {
    _docClickSub = document.onClick.listen((event) {
      print('Target:' + event.target.toString());
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    _docClickSub?.cancel();
    _docClickSub = null;
  }
}
```